# Bulk assign tags to work items in Visual Studio Online

Tags: project-management, tfs-workitem, azure-devops

I want to assign the same tag to multiple work items at once in Visual Studio Online.

I can edit fields in multiple work items at once using the following steps.

1. Run a query that will include all the items you want to bulk edit in the results.
2. Highlight all the items.
3. Right click and select "Edit selected work item(s)..."
4. Use the interface to select the field(s) you wish to edit and set the value.

The problem is that the tags are not listed as a field in the field dropdown. So I cannot set the tags using this method.

Is there a method I can use to bulk assign tags to work items?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use Microsoft Excel:

- Open Excel and start a new Sheet
- Go to the **Team** Tab
- Click **New List**
- Select your Team Project
- Select your Work Item Query
- If **Tags** are not part of your results:

  - Click on **Choose Columns** from the Ribbon Bar
  - Add the **Tags** column

Now just enter into the tags column in excel the tags you would like as a comma separated list.

Then just click "Publish" to push it back to TFS.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe in a future version they will add this functionality to VSO.

Comment: Maybe, the tag editing in Excel / API was only added a few sprints ago.

Comment: I've tried this in TFS 2012 and it appears NOT to work. The Tags field in my Excel sheet is read-only. Any suggestions?

Comment: @CamperWill as per my previous comment, this was added to VSO last year, but not TFS 2012 - It will probably be in TFS 2013.4. I still use TFS 2012 at work, and manually tagging lots of work items is a pain.